# Does anyone know how I can set unit test check-in policy for a selected portion of my source code in TFS 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, checkin-policy

In fact when I configure check-in policies for unit test it is applied for the overall solution but I need a customized unit test check-in policy to be able to limit the scope of the policy only to a specific project, source file or smaller portions of code so that when I check in code changes of a specific project ,test check in policy will be applied for it and not for other projects in the solution.

Comment: I'm just curious what check-in policies you enforce for Unit Test projects, that aren't available for other projects? Also did you look at creating custom policies http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/gg602484.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install the [TFS Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f) on the client computer then configure the Custom Path Policy to scope the check-in policy for unit test for a given path of your source control.